# How to halt execution in Vuejs until get request is finished

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code requesting data from an api endpoint:

```
fetchStudentMeta: function(){
    var vm = this;
    this.$http.get('/api/1.0/students/metadata/ '+ this.selectedStudent.id)
        .then(function (response){
            this.$set('meta', response.data);
            console.log(vm.meta); //line1
        });
    console.log(this.meta); //line2
},
```

In my console and execution, line 2 is processed before line 1. Any way to halt execution until my variable is set from the get request data?

Comment: do ajax async false until  get your response and  again make it synchronous

Comment: @NitinDhomse That is not a good practice, making the call synchronous just for sake of this purpose.

Comment: Do you want to just `log` some statement or anything else?

Comment: No, I want to the result of the get request and use it in a child component

Comment: @Rohit416 Yes I know, but we can do it till get response and revert it back to synchronous. like  jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});   jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});

Comment: Then you should put the code which depends up on the response inside the success handler.

Comment: @NitinDhomse Where does OP mentioned using `jQuery`? Besides it would be useless making the call `sync` and back to `async` again. The operation would be finished once you get the response. On the other hand, making it synchronous will block the UI interaction of user until the response comes back which would be a very bad user experience.

Comment: @Rohit416 thanks for the suggestion. I ended up setting a broadcast to alert my child component that data has been received then proceeding from there. Seemed like a much cleaner solution. I think it's worth pointing out that "then" in the promise from my code is the success handler

Comment: Actually `then` can take two callback functions, one for the success and other for failure like`then(successFn( ) {  }, failureFn( ) {  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is placed in `then()` closure which means will not be processed until the request is done while the second line is processed immediately once the request initiated.

The question is what's actually you're trying to do with `this.meta` attribute (line 2)? if you intend to cast it you can use `computed`, or you can `$dispatch()` or `$broadcast()` to trigger an event.

Comment: Thanks for seeing this mate, I actually ended up having a $broadcast that alerts the child component to start acting. I'm going to choose your answer based on that, you've hit the nail on the head.